# Encoding of SHP files and selecting

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr

I have a SHP file which have UTF8-encoded char fields. It also has a corresponding CPG file with the value 65001. The language byte (#29) in the DBF is currently 0.

How do I get it to keep the encoding in the output, when I use ogr2ogr to select a subset of the records? Output is also SHP. At the moment it changes it into $57 = codepage 1252.

Comment: Have you cpg file, cpg contains information about encoding? For example, if have you shapefile with encoding UTF-8, cpg file contains utf-8 string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this as part of the command line, does the trick:

```
-lco ENCODING=UTF-8
```